# Find all possible starting positions of a regular expression match in perl, including overlapping matches?

Tags: perl

Is there a way to find all possible start positions for a regex match in perl?

For example, if your regex was "aa" and the text was "aaaa", it would return 0, 1, and 2, instead of, say 0 and 2.

Obviously, you could just do something like return the first match, and then delete all characters up to and including that starting character, and perform another search, but I'm hoping for something more efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use lookahead:

```
$ perl -le 'print $-[0] while "aaaa" =~ /a(?=a)/g'
```

In general, put everything except the first character of the regex inside of the `(?=...)`.

Comment: An elegant one-liner.  But it is worth noting that the `put everything except the first char in (?=...)` transform will break down if the regex contains meta-characters at the start, or if the body contains alternations.

Comment: Yes, extra care is needed in situations like that.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

I thought about this one a bit more, and came up with this solution using an embedded code block, which is nearly three times faster than the `grep` solution:

```
use 5.010;
use warnings;
use strict;

{my @pos;
 my $push_pos = qr/(?{push @pos, $-[0]})/;

sub with_code {
    my ($re, $str) = @_;
    @pos = ();
    $str =~ /(?:$re)$push_pos(?!)/;
    @pos
}}
```

and for comparison:

```
sub with_grep {  # old solution
    my ($re, $str) = @_;
    grep {pos($str) = $_; $str =~ /\G(?:$re)/} 0 .. length($str) - 1;
}

sub with_while { # per Michael Carman's solution, corrected
    my ($re, $str) = @_;
    my @pos;
    while ($str =~ /\G.*?($re)/) {
        push @pos, $-[1];
        pos $str = $-[1] + 1
    }
    @pos
}

sub with_look_ahead {  # a fragile "generic" version of Sean's solution
    my ($re, $str) = @_;
    my ($re_a, $re_b) = split //, $re, 2;
    my @pos;
    push @pos, $-[0] while $str =~ /$re_a(?=$re_b)/g;
    @pos
}
```

Benchmarked and sanity checked with:

```
use Benchmark 'cmpthese';

my @arg = qw(aa aaaabbbbbbbaaabbbbbaaa);
my $expect = 7;

for my $sub qw(grep while code look_ahead) {
    no strict 'refs';
    my @got = &{"with_$sub"}(@arg);
    "@got" eq '0 1 2 11 12 19 20' or die "$sub: @got";
}

cmpthese -2 => {
    grep  => sub {with_grep      (@arg) == $expect or die},
    while => sub {with_while     (@arg) == $expect or die},
    code  => sub {with_code      (@arg) == $expect or die},
    ahead => sub {with_look_ahead(@arg) == $expect or die},
};
```

Which prints:

```
          Rate  grep while ahead  code
grep   49337/s    --  -20%  -43%  -65%
while  61293/s   24%    --  -29%  -56%
ahead  86340/s   75%   41%    --  -38%
code  139161/s  182%  127%   61%    --
```

Comment: Nice, but a little too brute-force. Better to do `while ($str =~ /\G$re/) { push @at, $-[0]; pos $str = $-[0] + 1 }` to only retry at positions following a successful match.

Comment: @Michael Carman => Agreed, see the update for a much faster solution.  Also, you need to put optional space between the `\G` and `$re` in your solution when matching something like `aaaabbaaa`, otherwise it will end too early.

Comment: Good catch. One minor bug in your embedded code version: using the `/x` modifier will break the pattern if `$re` contains whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for a regex, but there is actually a simple builtin function that does something quite similar, the function `index` ([`perldoc -f index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html)). From that we can build up a simple solution to your direct question, though if you really need a more complicated search than your example this will not work as it only looks for substrings (after an index given by the third parameter).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'aaaa';
my $substr = 'aa';

my $pos = -1;
while (1) {
  $pos = index($str, $substr, $pos + 1);
  last if $pos < 0;
  print $pos . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use global matching with the `pos()` function:

```
my $s1 = "aaaa";
my $s2 = "aa";

while ($s1 =~ /aa/g) {
    print pos($s1) - length($s2), "\n";
}
```